# How to create an "array of selectors"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, selector

I'm using the iPhone SDK (3.0) and I'm trying to create an **array of selectors** to invoke a variety of methods within one class.

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong (I think @selector isn't considered a class and so stuffing them into an NSArray isn't working).

I tried this, but it's obviously wrong.

**Is there a simple way to have an array of selectors like this?  Or is there a better way to iterate through a collection of methods?**

```
selectors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @selector(method1),
                          @selector(method2),
                          @selector(method3),
                          @selector(method4),
                          @selector(method5),
                          @selector(method6),
                          @selector(method7), nil];

for (int i = 0; i < [selectors count]; i++) {
    if ([self performSelector:[selectors objectAtIndex:i]]) // do stuff;
}
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Could you store strings and use  NSSelectorFromString?

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString)

```
NSSelectorFromString
```

Returns the selector with a given name.

```
SEL NSSelectorFromString (
   NSString *aSelectorName
);
```

Comment: Not an appropriate solution for when just an array of selectors is needed.

Comment: `NSPointerArray` is better.

Answer (score 44):

This creates an object out of selector:

```
[NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(x)]
```

Comment: How would you go about extracting the selector from this to be used by `performSelector:`?

Comment: @DeanKelly answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575055/how-to-build-a-nsarray-or-nsmutablearray-of-class-methods-in-objective-c by terry franguiadakis

Comment: Type cast is needed, as follows, `SEL x = (SEL)selectorValue.pointerValue;`

Answer (score 37):

Why not just use a simple C array?

```
static const SEL selectors[] = {@selector(method1),
                                ....
                                @selector(method7)};

...

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(selectors)/sizeof(selectors[0]); i++) {
  [self performSelector:selectors[i]];
  // ....
}
```

Comment: Good, but `static` is not needed here (initializer is not a compile-time constant).

Answer (score 13):

You can also create an array of `NSInvocation`s. This is handy if  you need an argument to go with your selector.

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [[yourTarget class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:yourSEL];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[inv setTarget:yourTarget];
[inv setSelector:yourSEL];
[inv setArgument:&yourObject atIndex:2]; // Address of your object
```

Comment: NSInvocation is too expensive.

Answer (score 1):

If the list is static, I'd go with KennyTM's solution, but if you need a dynamic array or set, another option, besides storing the selector string, is to create an object with an `SEL` property or ivar, and store that.

```
@interface SelectorObject : NSObject
@property (assign, readonly, nonatomic) SEL selector;
- (id)initWithSelector:(SEL)selector;
@end

@implementation SelectorObject
- (id)initWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _selector = selector;
  }
  return self;
}
@end
```

You could then add a `perform` method to the class as well, and implement the method call there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to supplement two methods of storing selectors in an array,

First, `NSPointerArray` can store opaque pointer, such as `SEL`, as [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/sel) said,

```
NSPointerArray *selectors = [[NSPointerArray alloc] initWithOptions: NSPointerFunctionsOpaqueMemory];
[selectors addPointer:@selector(onSendButton:)];
[button addTarget: self action:[selectors pointerAt:0] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Second, C-style array is much simpler,

```
SEL selectors[] = { @selector(onSendButton:) };
[button addTarget: self action:selectors[0] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Choose any as you wish.