# iOS Refactoring/design: One view controller to manage different models/streams?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, refactoring

I'm working on an app where I have different types of "streams" (think Twitter). In it I have a - pretty big - view controller that manages most of this. The stream consists of two main Entities - User and Post - in different formats. In the view controller I have a `NSSTring` property to determine what kind of stream it is. This leads to a lot of this:

```
if ([self.postType isEqualToString:@"stream"]) {

    // Do stuff

} else if [self.postType  ...
[...]
[...]
```

I don't know if this is the best solution design wise, and it leads to a lot of coupling. The good thing is that I avoid a lot of duplication. But is there a better/nicer way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef enum{
    stream,
    --,
    --
}postType;
```

better use like this..

```
  switch (_postType) 
    {
        case stream:
            //do what you want
            break;
        case --:
            break;
         case --:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Decided to go with this. Became much nicer. The other solution would be a huge rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to avoid inheritance, you can use different scheme for each stream.
Map your selectors for each stream type (for example, define an enum of selector indexes and an array of selectors for each scheme [C-style array] , [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226520/how-to-create-an-array-of-selectors-in-objective-c)).
Each scheme will just access a different selector array.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fine with inheritance, would that be a good option? Would it be better/possible to have a "Main" UITableView controller class and inherit that class in subclasses - the different streams?

Comment: if the behaviour is could be generalised in such a manner than yes. if not, implement one to answer your needs and override what need to be specific for the other stream