# Can I add IBActions to NSArray?

Tags: iphone, nsarray, ibaction

I've some IBActions, like

```
-(IBAction) doAdd; 
-(IBAction) doEdit;
```

I want to add those to an NSArray for passing it to some class as argument of a function. I am trying like

```
myArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:doAdd, doEdit, nil];
```

but its not working for me. Is there any way it can be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are not objects. You can not add a method as an object. What you can do is add a pointer to the method and than use it like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/575321/986169).

Comment: giorashc, thanks a lot :) Yes you're right, we can't add method as an object! Its useful.